# How to remove name space xmlns from the AddressValidatioRequest Tag in the XML request generated by WSDL class

Tags: apex, wsdl, wsdl2apex

Please Help. Want to remove Namespace from xml tag-

XML-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <env:Header />
   <env:Body>
      <AddressValidationRequest xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">
         <WebAuthenticationDetail>
            <UserCredential>
               <Key>*****</Key>
               <Password>****</Password>
            </UserCredential>
         </WebAuthenticationDetail>
         <ClientDetail>
            <AccountNumber>****</AccountNumber>
            <MeterNumber>****</MeterNumber>
            <Localization>
               <LanguageCode>EN</LanguageCode>
               <LocaleCode>us</LocaleCode>
            </Localization>
         </ClientDetail>
         <TransactionDetail>
            <CustomerTransactionId>AddressValidationRequest</CustomerTransactionId>
            <Localization>
               <LanguageCode>EN</LanguageCode>
               <LocaleCode>us</LocaleCode>
            </Localization>
         </TransactionDetail>
         <Version>
            <ServiceId>aval</ServiceId>
            <Major>4</Major>
            <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
            <Minor>0</Minor>
         </Version>
         <InEffectAsOfTimestamp>2017-05-10T14:30:03.1982091+05:30</InEffectAsOfTimestamp>
         <AddressesToValidate>
            <ClientReferenceId />
            <Contact>
               <PersonName>*****</PersonName>
               <CompanyName>*****</CompanyName>
               <PhoneNumber>*****</PhoneNumber>
               <EMailAddress>*****</EMailAddress>
            </Contact>
            <Address>
               <StreetLines>*****</StreetLines>
               <City>*****</City>
               <StateOrProvinceCode>CA</StateOrProvinceCode>
               <PostalCode>94608</PostalCode>
               <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
               <Residential>true</Residential>
            </Address>
         </AddressesToValidate>
      </AddressValidationRequest>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

WSDL class generated by salesforce-

```
 public class AddressValidationRequest {
    public fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.WebAuthenticationDetail WebAuthenticationDetail;
    public fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.ClientDetail ClientDetail;
    public fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.TransactionDetail TransactionDetail;
    public fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.VersionId Version;
    public String InEffectAsOfTimestamp;
    public fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.AddressToValidate[] AddressesToValidate;
    private String[] WebAuthenticationDetail_type_info = new String[]{'WebAuthenticationDetail','http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4',null,'1','1','false'};
    private String[] ClientDetail_type_info = new String[]{'ClientDetail','http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4',null,'1','1','false'};
    private String[] TransactionDetail_type_info = new String[]{'TransactionDetail','http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] Version_type_info = new String[]{'Version','http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4',null,'1','1','false'};
    private String[] InEffectAsOfTimestamp_type_info = new String[]{'InEffectAsOfTimestamp','http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4',null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] AddressesToValidate_type_info = new String[]{'AddressesToValidate','http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4',null,'0','-1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4','true','true'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'WebAuthenticationDetail','ClientDetail','TransactionDetail','Version','InEffectAsOfTimestamp','AddressesToValidate'};
}

public class AddressValidationServicePort {
    public String endpoint_x = 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/addressvalidation';
    public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
    public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
    public String clientCertName_x;
    public String clientCert_x;
    public String clientCertPasswd_x;
    public Integer timeout_x;
    private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4', 'fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4'};
    public fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.AddressValidationReply addressValidation(fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.WebAuthenticationDetail WebAuthenticationDetail,fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.ClientDetail ClientDetail,fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.TransactionDetail TransactionDetail,fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.VersionId Version,String InEffectAsOfTimestamp,fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.AddressToValidate[] AddressesToValidate) {
        fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.AddressValidationRequest request_x = new fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.AddressValidationRequest();
        request_x.WebAuthenticationDetail = WebAuthenticationDetail;
        request_x.ClientDetail = ClientDetail;
        request_x.TransactionDetail = TransactionDetail;
        request_x.Version = Version;
        request_x.InEffectAsOfTimestamp = InEffectAsOfTimestamp;
        request_x.AddressesToValidate = AddressesToValidate;
        fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.AddressValidationReply response_x;
        Map<String, fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.AddressValidationReply> response_map_x = new Map<String, fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.AddressValidationReply>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4/addressValidation',
          'http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4',
          'AddressValidationRequest',
          'http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4',
          'AddressValidationReply',
          'fedexComWsAddressvalidationV4.AddressValidationReply'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x;
    }
```

Expected XML request -(Tested in Postman)

`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <AddressValidationRequest>
         <WebAuthenticationDetail>
            <UserCredential>
               <Key>****</Key>
               <Password>****</Password>
            </UserCredential>
         </WebAuthenticationDetail>
         <ClientDetail>
            <AccountNumber>****</AccountNumber>
            <MeterNumber>****</MeterNumber>
            <Localization>
               <LanguageCode>EN</LanguageCode>
               <LocaleCode>US</LocaleCode>
            </Localization>
         </ClientDetail>
         <TransactionDetail>
            <CustomerTransactionId></CustomerTransactionId>
            <Localization>
               <LanguageCode>EN</LanguageCode>
               <LocaleCode>US</LocaleCode>
            </Localization>
         </TransactionDetail>
         <Version>
            <ServiceId>aval</ServiceId>
            <Major>4</Major>
            <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
            <Minor>0</Minor>
         </Version>
         <InEffectAsOfTimestamp>2015-03-09T01:21:14+05:30</InEffectAsOfTimestamp>
         <AddressesToValidate>
            <ClientReferenceId>ac vinclis et</ClientReferenceId>
            <Contact>
               <ContactId>****</ContactId>
               <PersonName>***</PersonName>
               <CompanyName>****</CompanyName>
               <PhoneNumber>*****</PhoneNumber>
               <EMailAddress>****</EMailAddress>
            </Contact>
            <Address>
               <StreetLines>4240 Holden Street</StreetLines>
               <City>Emeryville</City>
               <StateOrProvinceCode>CA</StateOrProvinceCode>
               <PostalCode>94698</PostalCode>
               <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
               <Residential>0</Residential>
            </Address>
         </AddressesToValidate>
      </AddressValidationRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

Comment: y do u want to remove the namespaces ? r u facing any issues ?

Comment: Fedex web service is unable to read the AddressValidationRequest tag because of namespace (xmlns). we have sent the same request without namespace and its working.

Comment: Can you share the SOAP request you are making that does work? It does look correct that `AddressValidationRequest` is in the `http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4` namespace as per the WSDL found at https://github.com/jzempel/fedex/blob/master/fedex/wsdls/AddressValidationService_v4.wsdl

Comment: Worst case you could modify the `*_type_info` elements to adjust the namespaces.

Comment: @Daniel Ballinger - Thanks for your response.
We have tried to modify *_type_info it will take 3 arguments as shown in the code. we applied many combinations but it's not working.
Can you please Share the modification needed to remove namespace.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP resolved by contacting FedEx and they corrected the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken your request body and run it using my test credential. I got a valid response by removing the empty XML tag in request body.

```
<ClientReferenceId />
```

Please remove the tag and try again. If this solve your issue please mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the error you are getting back from the webservice.

Having the namespace defined on the `AddressValidationRequest` element versus the `soapenv:Envelope` element shouldn't matter. I.e. You can define the default xmlns attribute anywhere. The only consequence is if any other namespace needs to be explicitly set on child elements.

Comment: Thanks Danial 
It was the FedEx web service error showing unrelated error i.e xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/addressvalidation/v4" unknown namespace and when we remove that namespace manually showing correct output, as desired.
We have raised the case in FedEx and received mail from FedEx that issue is resolved and now we have sent the same request without removing namespace and getting output. :)